# The click event is made but it isn't showed in the screen

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making a mobile application with phonegap and jquery mobile. Everytime I select one of the menu elements I call to a WS that gives me an answer that I show in the screen. It works perfectly up to there.

As I want to have a better view so I use the code trigger ('create'). (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html but insted of refresh I have to make an create)

```
var listadohtml = '<div data-role="fieldcontain"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup">';
for (var i=0;i<resultado.length;i++){
    var item = '';
    var id = resultado[i]['id'];
    item += '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-'+id+'" id="checkbox-'+id+'" class="custom" />';
    item += '<label for="checkbox-'+id+'">'+resultado[i]["title"]+'</label>';

    listadohtml += item;
}
listadohtml += '</fieldset></div>';
$('#listaPreguntas').html(listadohtml).trigger('create');
```

Inmediatly after that I associate an event:

```
$("#listaPreguntas input[type='checkbox']").bind( "click", function(event, ui) {... some code ...});
```

It shows everything fine, but the problem is that sometimes (not always, that's the problem) when I click a checkbox the green tick is not shown but the event change is made. When it happens I can see, by clicking in other part of the screen, that I have clicked before because it refreshes and shows the tick.

The conclussions I have

- It is not the AVD because im making all the tests in my mobile phone with android 4.0.
- It appears that its something of the code that includes jquery mobile when I use de trigger.
- I think it is not loading time because I can wait for years and it can happens.

As you can see its not a "logic" problem but a usability one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For checkbox and radio, use `change` event not `click`. And keep in mind that attaching events to dynamic elements is different, I have updated my answer accordingly.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/R7cAu/)**

```js
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that before changing to the change event and it had the same problem.

Comment: Sorry @Yises because they are dynamic, i'll update my answer.

Comment: Ive modified my 'bind' to your .on ('change'... and its the same. Sometimes it works and others the checkbox is "frozen" until I click in other side of the screen (and the event takes place and the tick appears). Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked my updates answer? @Yises use jquery 1.9 and jquerymobile 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

If the event click fires every time as expected then try to set the check box checked/unchecked classes using  addClass and removeClass in your code pragmatically rather than relying on the JQM.